# How to set up a proxy in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

In a react app, one creates a setupProxy.js file and puts the following in it:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api/*', 
        { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }
    ));
}
```

But when I do the same thing and put this same file in a react native directory, the proxy doesn't work and I get network error from the client side. How does one setup a proxy in react native to connect with the server?

--- edit ---

I tried doing the following:

```
const endpointMiddleware = createEndpointMiddleware({
    apis: {
        default: {
            apiUrl: 'localhost:5000/api/*',
        },
    },
});


const middlewares = [reduxThunk, endpointMiddleware, apiMiddleware];
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

But this hasn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using redux as your state manager you can use [redux-api-middleware endpoint package](https://github.com/TheSoftwareHouse/redux-api-middleware-packages/tree/master/packages/redux-api-endpoint-middleware). It worked for me.

Comment: Did you by any chance use axios and redux thunk? If so, can you show an example of how to set this proxy up for target localhost:5000 and /api/* path?

Comment: also, does the apiUrl property work with wildcards, i.e., *'s?